# Swift Array: Cannot invoke 'append' with an argument list of type '(Int)'

Tags: arrays, swift

I'm trying to implement a padding function for Array:

```
extension Array {
    func dataWithPadding(offset: Int, length: Int, paddingLength: Int) -> NSData {
        var arr = Array(self[offset..<(offset + length)])
        arr = arr.reverse()
        for (var i = 0; i < paddingLength; i++) {
            arr.append(0)
        }
        let d = NSData(bytesNoCopy: &arr, length: length)
        return d
    }
}
```

This errors at `arr.append` with:

> Cannot invoke 'append' with an argument list of type '(Int)'

I try to change the declaration into:

```
var arr[UInt8] = Array(self[offset..<(offset + length)])
```

However, this also errors:

> Cannot assign to immutable expression of type '[UInt8].Type' (aka 'Array.Type')

The weird part: I try to run the original code with `arr.append` commented out, and use `lldb` to directly run `arr.append(0)`, it actually works.

I'm using Xcode 7.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your Array extension puts no constraint on which types of arrays (element types) that can be used with it, `.append(0)` cannot be invoked; not all types can be converted into from integer literals. Hence, it's not weird that you cannot use `.append(0)` in the "generic" array extension, whereas you naturally can use it directly on an array that Swift can infer to have integer literal convertible elements, e.g. `[Int]`. Consider the following example:

```
var arr : [UInt8] = []
arr.append(0)

var arr2 : [String] = []
arr2.append(0)      // error
```

In the example above, both arrays would have access to your extension `dataWithPadding`, but both can naturally not make use of `arr.append(0)` in the extension, hence the error message

> Cannot invoke 'append' with an argument list of type '(Int)'

Now, a simple fix is to add a type constraint for the array elements to [`IntegerLiteralConvertible`](http://swiftdoc.org/v2.0/protocol/IntegerLiteralConvertible/), after which you extension is valid, and accessible for all arrays that have elements which conform to `IntegerLiteralConvertible`.

```
extension Array where Element: IntegerLiteralConvertible {
    func dataWithPadding(offset: Int, length: Int, paddingLength: Int) -> NSData {
        var arr = Array(self[offset..<(offset + length)])
        arr = arr.reverse()
        for (var i = 0; i < paddingLength; i++) {
            arr.append(0)
        }
        let d = NSData(bytesNoCopy: &arr, length: length)
        return d
    }
}
```

Alternatively, make use of the less general [`SignedNumberType`](http://swiftdoc.org/v2.0/protocol/SignedIntegerType/), [`UnSignedIntegerType`](http://swiftdoc.org/v2.0/protocol/UnsignedIntegerType/) or [`IntegerType`](http://swiftdoc.org/v2.0/protocol/IntegerType/) as type constraint for `Element`; these conform also to e.g. `Comparable` and `Equatable`, in case you'd like to compare and perform operations on your generic elements in the extension.

---

Finally note that you can naturally use your own custom protocol as type constraint for `Element` in your extension, allowing you to include additional blueprints (below, `foo()` method) accessible for your `Element`:s in the extension

```
protocol MyIntegerLiteralInitializableTypes: IntegerLiteralConvertible {
    func foo()
}
extension MyIntegerLiteralInitializableTypes {
    func foo() {
        print("I am of type \(self.dynamicType)!")
    }
}

/* For the Array<Type>:s you want to have access to .dataWithPadding,
extend those 'Type':s to MyIntegerLiteralInitializableTypes           */
extension Int8 : MyIntegerLiteralInitializableTypes { }
extension UInt8 : MyIntegerLiteralInitializableTypes { }

extension Array where Element: MyIntegerLiteralInitializableTypes {
    func dataWithPadding(offset: Int, length: Int, paddingLength: Int) -> NSData {

        self.first?.foo() /* I am of type ...! */

        var arr = Array(self[offset..<(offset + length)])
        arr = arr.reverse()
        for (var i = 0; i < paddingLength; i++) {
            arr.append(0)
        }
        let d = NSData(bytesNoCopy: &arr, length: length)
        return d
    }
}
```

It's also probably a good idea to add `@warn_unused_result` to your `dataWithPadding(...)` function signature, as a call to it without assigning the return will yield a runtime exception (*"... malloc: ...: pointer being freed was not allocated"*).

Comment: Thanks. Can I conform to other protocol while using `where` clause?

Comment: @skyline75489 Absolutely. An alternative is `IntegerType`, or a custom protocol of yours. For the latter, you must make sure the protocol includes the necessary blueprints for converting an integer literal into the element value.

Comment: Cool. Thanks man. Gotta say, the error is quite misleading for someone like me who does not know generics in Swift that well.

Comment: @skyline75489 Happy to help. To fully close the discussion for above, I'll add a simple example of writing your own custom protocol to use as type constraint.